# SQLException: Not a navigable ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy construyendo un sistema de hogares para los jugadores, usando MySQL como almacenamiento de estos hogares.

El problema es que raramente suele saltar la excepción del título:

```
[22:23:41 ERROR]: java.sql.SQLException: Not a navigable ResultSet.
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1804)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at it.thedarksword.essentialsvc.database.controller.DataController.loadHomes(DataController.java:116)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at it.thedarksword.essentialsvc.data.dao.impl.PlayerHomeDaoImpl.load(PlayerHomeDaoImpl.java:28)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at it.thedarksword.essentialsvc.listeners.PlayerListener.onJoin(PlayerListener.java:37)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.event.EventHandlerMethod.invoke(EventHandlerMethod.java:18)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:39)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.callEvent(PluginManager.java:416)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.connection.InitialHandler.lambda$finish$4(InitialHandler.java:618)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[22:23:41 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Lo que no logro entender es que esto sucede a veces y no con todos los jugadores.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public HashMap<UUID, List<PlayerHome>> loadHomes(DataDao<UUID, PlayerHome> homeDao) {
        HashMap<UUID, List<PlayerHome>> homes = new HashMap<>();
        List<PlayerHome> playerHomes = new ArrayList<>();
        database.open();

        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = this.database.getStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseManager.HOMES_TABLE);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(resultSet.getString("player_uuid"));
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                String server = resultSet.getString("server");
                String world = resultSet.getString("world");
                double x = resultSet.getDouble("x");
                double y = resultSet.getDouble("y");
                double z = resultSet.getDouble("z");
                float yaw = resultSet.getFloat("yaw");
                float pitch = resultSet.getFloat("pitch");
                ServerLocationObject serverLocationObject = new ServerLocationObject(server, world, x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
                PlayerHome playerHome = new PlayerHome(uuid, name, server, serverLocationObject);
                playerHome.setDataDao(homeDao);
                playerHomes.add(playerHome);
                homes.put(uuid, playerHomes);
            }
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }

        database.close();
        return homes;
    }
```

La línea 116 es `while (resultSet.next())`

El método de "loadHomes" se ejecuta cuando el jugador entra, entonces carga todos los hogares que están asociados a su UUID y las almacena dentro de una lista.

Estoy al pendiente de cualquier ayuda, gracias!